# How to call a method from a specific ancestor class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

Say, I have such a hierarchy:

```
class A
  def some_method
    'From A'
  end
end

class B < A
  def some_method
    'From B'
  end
end

class C < B
  def some_method
    # what's here to receive 'From A' ?
  end
end

c = C.new
c.some_method # get 'From A'
```

If I call `super` in C#some_method I'll receive 'From B'.
How should I implement C#some_method to get `'From A'` in `c.some_method`. 
What is the best practice to do this?

Comment: This could be fixed by having a `B2` class that branches from `B` without re-defining that method.

Comment: So you're saying that sometimes `C`s are `B`s and sometimes they're not? I'd tend to agree with @bjhaid here, `C < B` doesn't sound like the right approach (but I could be wrong).

Comment: Well, `C`s are `B`s, but they're also `A`s. So composition sounds good here.

Comment: where did my comment go? :o

Answer (score 5):

You can use "unbound methods" for this:

```
class A
  def some_method
    'From A'
  end
end

class B < A
  def some_method
    'From B'
  end
end

class C < B
  def some_method
    A.instance_method(:some_method).bind(self).call
  end
end

c = C.new
c.some_method # get 'From A'
```

Ruby has the capability to unbind a method from an object and then bind it to another object. The `instance_method` is used to grab a method object from the class rather than from a specific instance of this class. Later, we can bind that method to the instance of `C` that is calling `some_method`, that's it `self`, to finally call that method immediately in the same line.

As another user said, if your are doing this, you should probably review the desing of your program to use composition or another approach.

Comment: You are 1 second faster than I :D